# Remove path on double click d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have the following code to append a line on an SVG canvas. I am able to get the scope run when I double click on the path as the alert box pops up but the line itself doesn't gets removed. Where am I going wrong? Am I using `this` incorrectly?

```
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                     .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                     .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
                     .interpolate("step");

lineGraph = layer.append("path")
              .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
              .attr("stroke", "black")
              .attr("stroke-width", 1)
              .attr("fill", "none")
              .attr("id","aggregation")
              .attr("data", "newline")
              .style('marker-end', "url(#end-arrow)")
              .on("dblclick",function(d){
                alert("double");
                d3.this.remove();
              });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [`.remove()`](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Selections#remove) needs to be called on a D3 selection. In an event handler you can obtain the selection containing the element which was target of the event by doing

```
d3.select(this)
```

Thus, changing your handler to

```
.on("dblclick",function(d){
   d3.select(this).remove();
});
```

should do the trick.